# python: simple example for a python egg with a one-file source file?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I'm not quite sure how to build a really simple one-file source module. Is there a sample module out there one the web somewhere which can be built as a python .egg?

From the [setuptools page](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) it looks pretty simple, you just have your `setup.py` file and then at least one other .py file somewhere, and I can build an .egg file OK, and even install it using `easy_install`, but I can't seem to `import` the file from within python. (note: using 2.6.4)

---

here's my sample dir:

```
sconsconfig
   setup.py
   sconsconfig.py
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='sconsconfig',
      version='0.1',
      packages = find_packages(),
      )
```

sconsconfig.py:

```
def blarg(x):
  return x+1
```

If I run `setup.py bdist_egg` it then creates an egg file, but if I look in it, there's no .py source file....

Comment: Maybe you can check [this very simple example](http://mxm-mad-science.blogspot.com/2008/02/python-eggs-simple-introduction.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `py_modules` argument instead of the `packages` argument to list single file modules.

See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules

Answer (score 0):

For `distutils`, from https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example :

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['foo'],
      )
```

Then you only need a file:

```
foo.py
```

And in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo python setup.py
```

puts it under:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foo.py
```

without any directories.

Comment: It says "error: no commands supplied". I had to do "from setuptools import setup" and "python setup.py bdist_egg"

Comment: @lightbox142 thanks for the report. I don't have time to reproduce right now, let me know if you find something out! I should have made a minimal runnable example.