# How to execute a python command line utility from the terminal in any directory

Tags: python, macos, command-line

I have just written a python script to do some batch file operations. I was wondering how i could keep it in some common path like rest of the command line utilities like cd, ls, grep etc.

What i expect is something like this to be done from any directory -

$ script.py arg1 arg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the script directory into the PATH environment variable, or alternatively put the script in a location that is already in the PATH. On Unix systems, you usually use `/home/<nick>/bin` for your own scripts and add that to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory it is stored in to your PATH variable? From your prompt, I'm guessing you're using an sh-like shell and from your tags, I'm further assuming OS X. Go into your .bashrc and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to create a python package with entry points and install the program, rather than changing `$PATH` (using `setuptools` in `setup.py`). This has some advantages:

- Works outside of shells
- Reduces the amount of system-wide configuration, or at least puts it all in side the package.

See [Explain Python entry points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points) and [python: simple example for a python egg with a one-file source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852413/python-simple-example-for-a-python-egg-with-a-one-file-source-file) for details.

This has the advantage of keeping all your settings in one place.

You can use the `--develop` option so that you can still edit your code in place and the `--user` option to avoid messing python for other users.